# Problem 14 chapter 9 from PMA Rudin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

I have some problem with proving that $g$ is differentiable at $\mathbb{R}^1$. Let's prove that $g'(0)$ exists.
$$\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{g(t)-g(0)}{t}=\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(\gamma(t))-f(\gamma(0))}{t}=\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(\gamma(t))}{t}=$$ Let $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))$ and since $|\gamma'(0)|>0$ then $\gamma(t)\neq \mathbf{0}$ for enough small $t$ and then $f(\gamma(t))=\dfrac{\gamma_1^3(t)}{\gamma_1^2(t)+\gamma_2^2(t)}$. Hence $$\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(\gamma(t))}{t}=\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{\gamma_1^3(t)}{t(\gamma_1^2(t)+\gamma_2^2(t))}=\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{\left(\frac{\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_1(0)}{t}\right)^3}{\left( \frac{\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_1(0)}{t}\right)^2+\left( \frac{\gamma_2(t)-\gamma_2(0)}{t}\right)^2}=$$$$=\dfrac{\gamma_1'(0)}{|\gamma'(0)|^2}.$$ Since $|\gamma'(0)|^2>0$ then limit exists.

But how to prove that $g'(t_0)$ exists for $t_0\neq 0$? Because in this case $$\lim \limits_{t\to t_0}\dfrac{g(t)-g(t_0)}{t-t_0}=\lim \limits_{t\to t_0}\dfrac{f(\gamma(t))-f(\gamma(t_0))}{t-t_0}.$$ But in this case we have no information about $\gamma(t_0)$. I mean $\gamma(t_0)=0$ or $\gamma(t_0)\neq 0$ and this case we don't know what form has $f(\gamma(t_0))$. Also Chain rule is can not be applied here.

Can anyone please show the proof of this case?

Comment: if $\gamma(t_0) = (0, 0)$, you have proved it. Assume $\gamma(t_0) \ne 0$ now, it just likes chain-rule now.

Comment: @runaround, If we assume that $\gamma(t_0)\neq 0$ then OK. Why you think that $\gamma(t_0)$ is not equal to zero? We don't know that this curve is one-to-one!

Comment: if $\gamma(t_0) = (0, 0)$ is zero, just apply your proof. Only left is not zero.

Comment: @runaround,Sorry but if $\gamma(t_0)=(0,0)$ then $f(\gamma(t_0))=0$ but what about $f(\gamma(t))$ for $t\to t_0$? What form has $f(\gamma(t))$ for such $t$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a closer look to your argument, the condition $|\gamma'(t_0)|>0$ actually can be dropped. Assume that $\gamma(t_0) = 0$. You have whenever $t\neq t_0$,

$$\frac{f(\gamma(t))-f(\gamma(t_0))}{t-t_0} = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\left(\frac{\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_1(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right)^3}{\left( \frac{\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_1(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right)^2+\left( \frac{\gamma_2(t)-\gamma_2(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right)^2} & \text{if }\gamma(t)\neq 0 \\
0 & \text{if } \gamma(t) = 0\end{cases}$$

In particular, for all $t\neq t_0$,

$$\left| \frac{f(\gamma(t)-f(\gamma(t_0))}{t-t_0}\right| \le \left| \frac{\gamma_1(t) - \gamma_1(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right|.$$

If $\gamma'(t_0) = 0$, we have

$$\lim_{t\to t_0} \frac{\gamma_1(t) -\gamma_1(t_0)}{t} = 0, $$

so squeeze theorem implies that $g'(t_0)$ exists and

$$g'(t_0) = \lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{f(\gamma(t)-f(\gamma(t_0))}{t-t_0} = 0$$

Comment: What about differentiability of $g(t)$ at $t\neq 0$?

Comment: Yeah. When I was doing this, I found that the condition $|\gamma'(0)|>0$ was *useless* in both the two problems in part (c).

Comment: @Vim, Why it's useless? In my argument it guarantees that denominator is not equal to zero.

Comment: @RFZ: Please see the edit. Note that one can avoid the use of $|\gamma'(0)|>0$ to show that $g$ is differentiable at $0$, this is what I did in my answer.

Comment: @RFZ you could follow John Ma's approach.

Comment: @JohnMa, I looked at your edited post and may I ask you one question. In your edit $t_0\neq 0$?

Comment: Yes @RFZ. ($\gamma (0) = 0$ so $t_0$ is not zero)

Comment: @JohnMa, You mean that $\gamma$ is injective? If yes, then our $\gamma$ need not to be injective.

Comment: @RFZ. I misread your first comment, please see the edit again. It is just a small modification of the first edit, changing all $0$ to $t_0$.

Comment: @JohnMa, But in your solution you are using that $\gamma'(t_0)=0$ which is not given in condition. It seems weird

Comment: @RFZ : If $\gamma'(t_0) \neq 0$, your method works well. So I deal only with the case $\gamma'(t_0 )=0$.

Comment: @JohnMa, Ok. Please give me please some time to grasp it.

Comment: @JohnMa, I attentively read your post. You wrote that "for all $t\neq 0$ we have $\left|\dfrac{f(\gamma(t))-f(\gamma(t_0))}{t-t_0}\right|\leqslant \left|\dfrac{\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_1(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right|$". I understand how you got this inequality but why you wrote "for all $t\neq 0$". I guess that for holding this inequality we must have $\gamma_1(t)\neq 0$. But you wrote just $t\neq 0$. 
The problem is that there is possibly some non-zero point $t_1$ such $\gamma(t_1)=0$

Comment: The crucial moment is that: So $\left(\frac{\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_1(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\gamma_2(t)-\gamma_2(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right)^2\geqslant \left(\frac{\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_1(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right)^2$ then $$\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_1(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\gamma_2(t)-\gamma_2(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right)^2}\leqslant \dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_1(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right)^2}$$

Comment: Note that if $\gamma(t)=0$, the inequality is trivial as the left hand side is $0$. @RFZ

Comment: It should be $t\neq t_0$ instead.

Comment: @JohnMa, Can we continue our discussion in chat please?